# How to concatenate data in PowerApps selected in PowerBI

Tags: powerapps

Currently, in my PowerApps I have added a gallery with "PowerBIIntegration.Data" in the Items property, then I added a label into that gallery with the Text property as "ThisItem.'My column'".  So now in my PowerBI report the values I select in 'My Column' will appear in the app as shown in the picture attached.

My question is, how can I display my data in the PowerApp like in the screenshot except instead my data will appear side to side separated by a comma? So for example it would be "Plan 1, Plan 1+Inc Covid Adj, Plan 2, (plus additional fields the user select in PowerBI).

I have tried using just the Text Input without the gallery but when I enter "PowerBIIntegration.Data.'My Column' into the Default property I get the error saying that it expects a text value. What other methods can I use to make it work outside of using a gallery? Thanks in advance!

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have a label or text input in your PowerApps (outside the Gallery) you can use the Concat Function.

So your formula for the Text property might be something like:

```
Concat(PowerBIIntegration.Data, 'My Column', ", ")
```

Concat Function Syntax:

```
Concat(Table, Formula)
Concat(Table, Formula, Separator)
```